# Python FileNotFoundError when reading a file in the same directory using pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, pathlib, filenotfounderror

**Problem:**

I’m working through the book “Python Crash Course” by Eric Matthes, and I’ve encountered a problem while trying to read a file named ‘pi_digits.txt’ using Python. Here’s the code I’m using:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Specify the path to the 'pi_digits.txt' file
path = Path('pi_digits.txt')

# Read and print the contents of the file
contents = path.read_text()
print(contents)
```

When I run this code, I get an error stating that there’s no such file or directory named ‘pi_digits.txt’. However, I’ve confirmed that the file is in the same directory as my Python script. Here is the error as reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\python_work\files_and_exceptions\file_reader.py", line 8, in <module>
    contents = path.read_text()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1058, in read_text
    with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1044, in open
    return io.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'
```

**What I’ve tried:**

I’ve also tried specifying the path to the file as `files_and_exceptions/pi_digits.txt` which works correctly. But according to the book, the original code should work as well.

Here are the troubleshooting steps I’ve taken:

- Checked that the file is in the same directory as my Python script.
- Ensured there are no spaces at the start or end of the file name and checked the spelling multiple times.
- Verified that I have full control over the file’s permissions (I can view, modify, and save the file).

Despite these steps, the issue persists. I’m not sure what else to try and would appreciate any help or suggestions. P.S. I know that `files_and_exceptions/pi_digits.txt` works correctly, I was just wondering why `pi_digits.txt` does not work.

Comment: what's the output of [`print(os.getcwd())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)?

Comment: The output of `print(os.getcwd())` is the following: `C:\Users\username\python_work.`

Comment: can you post the full path containing your 'pi_digits.txt'? Something like this "c:\Users\username\python_work\folder_containing_file\pi_digits.txt"

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question I can modify the code to `files_and_exceptions/pi_digits.txt` with no issue and get a correct output. Similarly, your advice would certainly work. However, I am curious about the fact that `path = Path('pi_digits.txt')` doesn't work for me and that same peice of code for someone else would work.

Comment: Some editors, such as VS Code, don't necessarily execute the file from the directory where it's saved. I believe VS Code executes from whatever directory you first opened. So if you opened python_work/, then it's going to look there for the file you're trying to open. If you close all your files and folders and then quit VS Code, then open just the file you're currently working on, this will likely work.

Comment: I understand that opening the directory you are working on executes from that perspective but for some reason my code does not work. Thank you for responding to me, I appreciate your answer. I will continue on my coding journey past this minor barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read contents in your file using relative path, ensure that the file is located in the same directory as your python script. Then use this:

```
filename = 'pi_digits.txt'

# Read and print the contents of the file
with open(filename, 'r') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
```

Comment: As a somewhat beginner at Python coding I don't understand what this line of code is executing `with open(filename, 'r') as file_object:` I know it may be an easy concept to grasp for someone with plenty of experience, but I want to fully understand the code you provided. Furthermore, in the book "Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes, his code worked perfectly fine and stated that writing `pi_digits.txt` is all the `Path` needs to access the file due to the file being saved in the same directory as the .py file. Not to be rude, I just want to know why my duplicate piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: The with statement  simplifies the management of common file resources eliminating the need to close the file as it automatically closes the file after your program is done. Before, you would have to do something like file.close() but the with statement does that for you. That line says you should open the file in read mode. If you wanted to write to the file, you would use something like `with open(filename, 'w') as file_object`

Comment: See [with statement in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) to learn more about the with statement.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I forgot to check your piece of code earlier and got an error message. Here is the error message provided down below: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\python_work\files_and_exceptions\file_reader.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_object:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'`

Comment: Please what is the error message? Can't see it. BTW the code works well on my system. Be sure that your text file is in the same location as your python script. Also look at the link i included in my previous comment.

Comment: Refresh your page and it should show the error message.

Comment: Do you have this file `'pi_digits.txt'` in the same directory as your python script?

Comment: Yes, I think so, it is in the same folder as the file with my current code that I am having a problem with. I am using the platform VS Code to write my code.

Comment: you don't have to think so. Please be sure that you have a text file named `pi_digits.txt` there. Also take note of the underscore between pi and digits NOT HYPHEN.

Comment: Yes, the file `pi_digits.txt` is 100% there. I checked that the underscore is not a hyphen multiple times. In addition, if two files are in the same folder then that means those two files are in the same directory. I can CLEARLY see that they are in the same exact folder.

Comment: So have you resolved your issue? We can use absolute paths. Provide the full path to your file.

Comment: I have solved the issue: `folder/pi_digits.txt` works. I am just puzzled why `pi_digits.txt` doesn't work in this situation and that's all. I thank you for your patience and excellent responses.