How do I rectify no such file found with path problem?
Path issue
Like other newbies, it is hard to know the right question to ask. Why won't my path find the txt file in the same directory?
I am following a text to learn Python. I expected the txt file to be found since it is in the same directory. I found a workaround using the full path with r. ie. r"c:/user/.vscode/...". But, I would like this to work as it should and I believe I may have made a mistake somewhere that is causing this. Thank you for any help!

Make sure to save alice.txt. the white dot next to the name means it is not saved.

Thank you. I am reading more about current working directories. I think I am on the right PATH.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790161/python-filenotfounderror-when-reading-a-file-in-the-same-directory-using-pathlib#77790262
